# Customise NSPathControl

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nspathcontrol

I would like to make a custom `NSPathControl`.
`NSPathCell` has the method `+ pathComponentCellClass`, where you can return the custom class of the component cells.
I have a `NSPathComponentCell` subclass, which I return right there, but it doesn't work. 
The method does not get called. Why?

In the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/NSPathCell_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSPathCell/pathComponentCellClass) is says:

> Subclasses can override this method to return a custom cell class that is automatically used. By default, the method returns [NSPathComponentCell class], or a specialized subclass thereof.

If this is wrong, is there another way to customise `NSPathControl`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution and posted it on [github](https://github.com/iluuu1994/Pathbar).
I subclassed from NSPathControl. It's pretty simple actually.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the component cell class is archived by IB. So, if a path control is set up in IB, it won't use your override of `+pathComponentCellClass` unless and until you change its URL after loading the NIB. There may be other changes that provoke it, too, like setting the path style.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to modify [NSPathControlItem/attributedTitle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspathcontrolitem/1388287-attributedtitle):

(Limitation: macOS 10.10+)